# DB2 : update multiple row by referring other table matching rows

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

I have problem to create single SQL statement to UPDATE multiple row of REJECTFG for table DBKD1.DADEOUTL
by referring NREJECTFG from table DBKD1.WADEOUTL. The data should match by concatenate 2 field which is
A.SUBLOTNO || A.SLOTSEQ = B.RSUBLOTNO || B.RSLOTSEQ

TABLE DBKD1.DADEOUTL

```
SUBLOTNO---------SLOTSEQ--------REJECTFG

1VNJX00G04--------12----------------C   
1VNJX00G04--------15----------------C   
1VEPD04G00--------3-----------------M   
1VEPD04G00--------1-----------------K   
1VNRJ00G00--------18----------------G   
1VNRK00G00-------16----------------J
```

TABLE DBKD1.WADEOUTL

```
RSUBLOTNO----------RSLOTSEQ------NREJECTFG 

1VEPD04G00----------3----------------X      
1VEPD04G00----------1----------------Y
```

After SQL Statement executed, table DBKD1.DADEOUTL should update like this

```
SUBLOTNO-----------SLOTSEQ--------REJECTFG

1VNJX00G04---------12----------------C   
1VNJX00G04---------15----------------C   
1VEPD04G00---------3-----------------X   
1VEPD04G00---------1-----------------Y   
1VNRJ00G00---------18----------------G   
1VNRK00G00--------16-----------------J
```

I need single SQL Statement than can update DBKD1.DADEOUTL based on whatever data in DBKD1.WADEOUTL